# Tag for square roots and radicals

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

In [the tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/roots/info) and tag-exceprt for [roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roots) the following is mentioned:

> For questions about "square roots", "cube roots", and such, consider using the (arithmetic) tag.

The tag [arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) indeed mention radicals as one of its uses, this is how the [tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/arithmetic/info) looks at the moment:

> Questions on basic arithmetic, e.g. addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, powers, radicals, etc.

But now there also exists a tags name [radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radicals). (The tag-wiki is empty at the moment.) So this seems as a better candidate for questions about square roots, cube roots etc. Or would it be a better solution to get rid of the [radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radicals) tag and merge it into [arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)?

Comment: Personally, when I see the question where radicals seem to be relevant, I usually add both ([tag:arithmetic]) and ([tag:radicals]). (Since both tag exist, I do use them. Of course, if most users will say that some of these two tags is not needed, I will follow community consensus.)

Comment: Two questions stood out to me in the radicals tag: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530766/determine-the-radical-sqrtm-mathbbz and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473223/radical-of-pullback They probably need to be retagged if we are going to do any systematic treatment of that tag and its contents.

Comment: Didn't we discuss the radicals tag on meta before? I have a feeling that I already made some jokes about free radicals of right ideals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Your joke is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11751/nested-radicals-tag#comment45703_11751).

Comment: Ah, thanks. More and more radicals... [insert a relevant joke here] LOL. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila You were right there already was a question about this tag, I have forgotten about it :-( [About a new (radicals) tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10705/about-a-new-radicals-tag)

Comment: I forgot about that as well! :-)